# Regex not correctly matching

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Please do not be alarmed at the huge walls of text. This is not a very expert question and does not require *much* reading.
Problem:
I have a group of regexes in an array that are ran through and go through a string, matching and wrapping text around the match.
I am having a lot of problems with this and I have no clue why. Most of my regexes are not matching correctly with this string:

```
var changelog = `+ = Added
- = Removed
~ = Changed
[line]
v1 - 4chan Enhancer is released
[line]
v2 - Minor update
Added support for new settings in the future
[line]
v3 - Major update
+ Infinite scrolling
+ Remove ads completely
+ Fetch replies automatically
+ Remove comic at top
+ Random Pepe
+ Blocked keywords
+ Changelog
+ Version
[line]
If you would like to request more features, please email me at billy@billyvenner.co.uk`;
```

If I run the regexes, the function returns this:

```
<span style='color: #009<span style='color: #009110'>1</span>10'>+</span> = Added
<span style='color: #FF0000'>-</span> = Remo<span style='color: #009110'>v</span>ed
~ = Changed
[line]
v1 - 4chan Enhancer is released
[line]
v2 - Minor update
Added support for new settings in the future
[line]
v3 - Major update
+ Infinite scrolling
+ Remove ads completely
+ Fetch replies automatically
+ Remove comic at top
+ Random Pepe
+ Blocked keywords
+ Changelog
+ Version
[line]
If you would like to request more features, please email me at billy@billyvenner.co.uk
4chan Enhancer v3
```

Observing the new changelog using regex101 and running my regexes through it, I am returned with exactly what I'm trying to match.
For some odd reason, all of them only get matches once or zero times. Here's the array that the regexes are in:

```
var formats = [
        ["^(\\+).*","<span style='color: #009110'>","</span>"],
        ["^\[line\]","<hr>","",false],
        ["^(\\~).*","<span style='color: #0086E0'>","</span>"],
        ["^(\\-).*","<span style='color: #FF0000'>","</span>"],
        ["^(v[0-9]+).*","<span style='color: #009110'>","</span>"],
        ["(http[s]{0,1}:\\/\\/www\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:\\/|-|_|=|\\?|&|[a-zA-Z0-9])*)",linkify],
        ["((?:\\/|-|_|=|\\?|&|[a-zA-Z0-9])*@(?:\\/|-|_|=|\\?|&|[a-zA-Z0-9])*\\..*\\.(?:\\/|-|_|=|\\?|&|[a-zA-Z0-9])*)",function() {linkify("mailto")}],
    ];
```

If you try running these regexes through my changelog, it works fine.
Please note with the above regexes: you can see the double backslashes because of the escaping character in JavaScript (so they are actually just one backslash in the actual regex) and the two regexes at the bottom are being implemented later and currently do nothing in my code.
Here is the actual code to run through these regexes:

```
function linkify(before) {

}
function colorChangelog() {
    var newChangelog = "";
    newChangelog = changelog;
    var formats = [
        ["^(\\+).*","<span style='color: #009110'>","</span>"],
        ["^\[line\]","<hr>","",false],
        ["^(\\~).*","<span style='color: #0086E0'>","</span>"],
        ["^(\\-).*","<span style='color: #FF0000'>","</span>"],
        ["^(v[0-9]+).*","<span style='color: #009110'>","</span>"],
        ["^(http[s]{0,1}:\\/\\/www\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:\\/|-|_|=|\\?|&|[a-zA-Z0-9])*)",linkify],
        ["^((?:\\/|-|_|=|\\?|&|[a-zA-Z0-9])*@(?:\\/|-|_|=|\\?|&|[a-zA-Z0-9])*\\..*\\.(?:\\/|-|_|=|\\?|&|[a-zA-Z0-9])*)",function() {linkify("mailto")}],
    ];

    for (y = 0; y < formats.length; y++) {
        console.log(y);
        var leregex = new RegExp(formats[y][0],"g")
        var executed2 = leregex.exec(newChangelog);
        if (!!leregex.exec(newChangelog)) {
            if (!!leregex.exec(newChangelog)[1]) {
                var executed = executed2[1];
                for (match = 0; match < executed.length; match++) {
                    if (typeof(formats[y][1]) == "string") {
                        if (formats[y][formats[y].length-1] != false) {
                            var newstr = formats[y][1] + executed[match] + formats[y][2];
                            newChangelog = newChangelog.replace(executed[match],newstr);
                        } else {
                            var newstr = formats[y][1] + formats[y][2];
                            newChangelog = newChangelog.replace(executed[match],newstr);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (typeof(formats[y][1]) == "function") {

                        } else {
                            console.log("Invalid 2nd argument: " + formats[y][1]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(newChangelog);
    }
    changelog = newChangelog + `
4chan Enhancer ` + version;
};
colorChangelog();
console.log(changelog);
```

I am using `new RegExp` to run my regexes with the flags `"gm"` with the `g` meaning it will match as much as possible and the `m` meaning it will start `^`s and `$`s at the start/end of the **line**.
Thank you for reading this huge daunting block of text, I hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with your usage of exec. `.exec()` will return the first matched instance not yet returned.  Drop the exec into a while loop and you should get what you need. You need to make sure you dont have anything inside the loop that will turn this into an infinite issue.  changing your for loop to the following appears to work:

```
for (y = 0; y < formats.length; y++) {
  //console.log(y);
  var leregex = new RegExp(formats[y][0], "gm")
  while (!!(executed2 = leregex.exec(newChangelog))) {
    //console.log(executed2)
    if (!!executed2[1]) {
      if (typeof(formats[y][1]) == "string") {
        if (formats[y][formats[y].length - 1] != false) {
          var newstr = formats[y][1] + executed2[0] + formats[y][2];
          newChangelog = newChangelog.replace(executed2[0], newstr);
        } else {
          var newstr = formats[y][1] + formats[y][2];
          newChangelog = newChangelog.replace(executed2[0], newstr);
        }
      } else {
        if (typeof(formats[y][1]) == "function") {

        } else {
          console.log("Invalid 2nd argument: " + formats[y][1]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //console.log(newChangelog);
}
```

I instantiated executed2 at the top of the function:

```
var newChangelog = "", executed2;
```

Uncomment the console.logs to see the states scroll by.

You might want to rename some of the vars to make more sense (specifically the executed2 var, as executed no longer exists

I used [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) from developer.mozilla.org for info on `.exec`